# Angular router redirects to same route just adds login at the end

Tags: angular, angular-router

This Error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login/home'`.
is basically my problem, I want it to redirect to `http://localhost:4200/home not http://localhost:4200/login/home`
this is my routing module

```
  { path:'', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardService] } ,
  { path:'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardService] } , 
  { path:'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path:'register', component: RegisterComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

and this is the calling code this.router.navigate([''])
```

Comment: Your code tries to redirect to `login/home` path that not valid, and you get some error try to use the absolute redirect that I say in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the login component and any public component from the home component and another with using a different `router-outlet` tag like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And your router module and routes items like this:

```
    { path:'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path:'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path:'', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path:'home', component: HomeComponent
    , canActivate:[AuthGuardService] 
    , children: [
         {path: 'child-a',
          component: ChildAComponent
         }
      ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },  // Wildcard route for a 404 page
```

And then you can use these router links:

```
http://localhost:4200/login
http://localhost:4200/register
http://localhost:4200/home
http://localhost:4200/home/child-a
```

like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
this.router.navigate(['/register']);
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
this.router.navigate(['/home/child-a']);
this.router.navigate(['/']);
```

For more info: [angular.io/guide/router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: I have added <router-outlet></router-outlet> to both the app and home component like you said but I get the same problem when I try to use the login it just redirects to /login/home? Am I missing something?

Comment: @tonygeorgiev Please add more info to help you. or use this link: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/config and this: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/route-configuration/

Comment: @tonygeorgiev after add outlets use my recommended router config